# Taking 2 PDF images and putting them together in a single PDF page?

Tags: pdf, coldfusion

I am trying to take two PDF images and merging them onto one PDF page.  The reason it has to be in PDF is because JPG is lossy and will not generate a crisp image for print.  Is their a way in Coldfusion 9 to merge these 2 PDF images?

Note: I did find a plugin for photoshop that supposedly makes JPG lossless. CFIMAGE will be able to do my task without a problem if that's the case.  I want to see if CFPDF has some trick that I do not know about first before I go and explore this lossless JPG option.

Comment: How are you wanting to merge the images?  On top of each other or below/beside each other?

Comment: I did just learn CF9 cfimage can use TIFF format, which is lossless.  So I merged 2 TIFF files into one 1 tiff file and it came out loseless.  Which is great, however how do I turn that final tiff into a pdf?

Comment: You're in luck cause I'm pretty sure that cfdocument supports creating PDFs from Tiff images.

Comment: Ok so I think I figured it out...

Use CFIMAGE to manipulate the different loseless tiff files, then use 

   <cfdocument format="pdf" name="temp"> 
   <img src="test.tif"> 
   </cfdocument> 

<cffile action="write" file="#APPLICATION.config.serverpath#/test.pdf" output="#temp#">

to generate the final PDF.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I think I figured it out...

Trying to manipulate PDF files onto a single page is NOT possible.  I found CF9 CFIMAGE tag supports TIFF format which is lossless. So using 2 TIFF sources files VS 2 PDF source files allows me to use CFIMAGE to manipulate the lossless TIFF files

```
<cfimage source="#APPLICATION.config.serverpath#/background.tif" name="Background">
<cfimage source="#APPLICATION.config.serverpath#/ad1.tif" name="ad1">
<cfimage source="#APPLICATION.config.serverpath#/ad2.tif" name="ad2">

<cfset height1 = ImageGetHeight(ad1)> 
<cfset width1  = ImageGetWidth(ad1)>
<cfset height2 = ImageGetHeight(ad2)> 
<cfset width2  = ImageGetWidth(ad2)>
<cfset resImage1 = ImageCopy(ad1,0,0,width1,height1)> 
<cfset resImage2 = ImageCopy(ad2,0,0,width2,height2)>
<cfset ImagePaste(Background,resImage1,0,0)> 
<cfset ImagePaste(Background,resImage2,0,height1)> 

<cfimage source="#Background#" 
         action="write" 
         destination="#APPLICATION.config.serverpath#/test.tif" 
         overwrite="yes">

<cfdocument format="pdf" name="temp"> 
<img src="test.tif"> 
</cfdocument> 

<cffile action="write" 
        file="#APPLICATION.config.serverpath#/test.pdf" 
        output="#temp#">
```

to generate the final PDF.

Comment: Good job. Just FYI, in the above code # signs are only needed when using a variable inside quotes.